# Adding summary for group section in crystal report

Tags: filter, crystal-reports, summary, cumulative-sum

I am designing a report in which I filter the data and then add a group. I also add a summary field to show the sum of the cost of items in the group. But The amount of sum is not correct, it shows the sum of all items in the group without considering the criteria to filter the data (It sum the cost of all item). However, in the group I have 5 items and the sum should show the sum of cost for these 5 items not all items. But If I use the running total for the cost, it shows the right amount. How can I solve the problem in using the summary field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you putting the summary field in the group footer? A running total field in CR will come up with different sums depending on where you put it in the report, so you have to be a bit careful.